# PyQt Window construction

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Can someone explain to me the difference between the following two code examples? Why is the top one not working? It executes without error, but the window doesn't stay open.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
QtGui.QMainWindow().show()
app.exec_()
```

and:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `QtGui.QMainWindow().show()` you are creating an object of `QMainWindow` and you are showing it. But you do no save that instance of the `QMainWindow` in your memory. So eventually python's garbage collection deletes that instance and your `QMainWindow` no longer shows.

In the second code: `win = QtGui.QMainWindow()` you save the object instance of `QMainWindow` to `win` in your memory. Python does not consider that as garbage because it is in use and hence your window stays open